# Setting up Netty (or Spark) to provide the output of kotlin-js module as static

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I try to create a whole-stack project using Kotlin. As multiplatform projects are experimental in Kotlin, there is not much information available, so I tried to start from the project skeleton of IDEA project wizard (Kotlin > JS Client and JVM Server). It generates the base code and even adds a "hello world" type of example code.

However, when I build the project and start it (gradle run), the web page console tells me the kotlin-js package is not available:

```
The script from “http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/piggy-bank.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/piggy-bank.js”. [127.0.0.1:8080:8:1](http://127.0.0.1:8080/)
```

The example uses Netty as embedded web server and the pre-generated code is:

```
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8091, host = "127.0.0.1") {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondHtml {
                head {
                    title("Hello from Ktor!")
                }
                body {
                    +"${hello()} from Ktor. Check me value: ${Sample().checkMe()}"
                    div {
                        id = "js-response"
                        +"Loading..."
                    }
                    script(src = "/static/piggy-bank.js") {}
                }
            }
        }
        static("/static") {
            resource("piggy-bank.js")
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```

It looks the compiled js code in the `static` folder, however, the gradle task doesn't creates, nor copies the generated file into static folder.

With some refactoring I managed the example to work. First I located the required code and have found in `build/js/packages/piggy-bank/kotlin`, so I altered the static configuration:

```
val buildDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/build"
val jsDir = "$buildDir/js/packages/piggy-bank/kotlin"
val jsImpDir = "$buildDir/js/packages_imported/kotlin/1.3.50"

embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8090, host = "127.0.0.1") {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondHtml {
                head {
                    title("Hello from Ktor!")
                }
                body {
                    +"${hello()} from Ktor. Check me value: ${Sample().checkMe()}"
                    div {
                        id = "js-response"
                        +"Loading..."
                    }
                    // Note, that I had to add Kotlin system js file manually!
                    script(src = "/static/kotlin.js") {}
                    script(src = "/static/piggy-bank.js") {}
                }
            }
        }
        static("static") {
            // Here comes the new references
            files( "$jsDir")
            files( "$jsImpDir")
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```

This temporally solves the problem, but works only within IDEA (refereing directly to the build folder). What the correct solution should be, that the gradle build script creates a self containing, fully operational code.

Here is my (also generated) gradle file (I've migrated from Groovy to Kotlin DSL):

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpack

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform") version "1.3.50"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven(  "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" )
    mavenCentral()
}

val ktor_version = "1.1.3"
val logback_version = "1.2.3"

kotlin {
    js {
        browser {  }
    }
    jvm {
        compilations.named("main") {
            tasks.getByName<Copy>(processResourcesTaskName) {
                dependsOn("jsBrowserWebpack")
                 tasks.named<KotlinWebpack>("jsBrowserWebpack") {
                     println(this.outputs)
                     from(entry.name, destinationDirectory)
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
                        dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }

        named("jvmMain") {
            dependencies {
                implementation( kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
                implementation( "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
                implementation( "io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version")
                implementation( "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
            }
        }

        named("jvmTest") {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-testng"))
            }
        }

        named("jsMain") {
            dependencies {
                implementation( kotlin("stdlib-js"))
            }
        }
        named("jsTest") {
            dependencies {
                implementation( kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }


    }
}


tasks.register<JavaExec>("run") {
    dependsOn("jvmJar")
    group = "application"
    main = "sample.SampleJvmKt"
    val t = tasks.named<Jar>("jvmJar")

    classpath(configurations.named("jvmRuntimeClasspath"), t.get() )
}
```

How should I change the build file to build correct code?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the problem with `"org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform" 1.3.50`, but failed to reproduce with `1.3.61`. Can you check it with your project?